# How to change Class Variable from function in another Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-class

As you can see from below code i want to change Company class name variable from Owner class change_company_name function
How can ı do that ?
thanks

```
class Company:
    name = "A Company name"
    def __init__(self,num_of_employees,found_year):
        self.num_of_employees = num_of_employees
        self.found_year = found_year

class Owner:
    Company.name = "I know that here is changing the Company name"

    def change_company_name(self):       ### I want to change Company name from function in another Class
        Company.name = "Another Company Name"


print(Company.name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is `correct`, you just have to `call` the method of the class.

```
class Company:
    name = "A Company name"
    def __init__(self):
        # i removed the params to 
        # make a simple example
        pass

class Owner:
    # its working
    Company.name = "I know that here is changing the Company name"

    def change_company_name(self):
        # and its working
        Company.name = "Another Company Name"


# create an object of the class
# in order the change through the function
o = Owner()
o.change_company_name()

print(Company.name)
```

out

```
Another Company Name
```

and if i comment the `method call`

```
o = Owner()
# o.change_company_name()

print(Company.name)
```

output

```
I know that here is changing the Company name
```